# rails app on aws fargate, cant connect via browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, aws-fargate

I'm trying to launch a simple rails app on Fargate. I've been following this tutorial: https://scoutapm.com/blog/deploying-to-aws-part-i-running-a-rails-app-on-fargate

I can see the puma server running in the logs listening on `localhost:80` but when I navigate to the public IP of the ENI I can't connect to the server.

Any suggestions on what the issue could be? I've made sure the security group is open to all traffic both inbound and outbound.

Answer (score 1):

binding '0.0.0.0' fixed it

`rails s -p 80 -b '0.0.0.0'`